# Get & set in Java returns null value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, get

I apologies in advance if the question is very basic but I'm a beginner to this.

How to get a value from one servlet(java) file to another. I'm able to print variable(strDateOfPurchase) value on "A" java file but printing on "B" gives null value which further gives me java.text.ParseException.

This is how it is get & set in "A" java file.

```
String strDateOfPurchase = pr.getQualifiedParameter("DOP");

getQuoteABCDO.setStrDateOfPurchase(strDateOfPurchase);
```

.......................
This is how it is defined in "B" java file. which prints null value ...............................

```
String strDateOfPurchase = null; 

getRevisedQuoteABCDO.setStrABCVehicleDateOfPurchase(strDateOfPurchase);

getQuoteABCDO.getStrDateOfPurchase();
```

Comment: you are initializing String strDateOfPurchase = null; with null so it will set to null and prints null. please explain your exact flow , how you are going to other servlet etc

Comment: you need to set session attribute in file A with session.setAttribute("key" , "yourstrdatepurchase") and then get this value back in your file B with session.getAttribute("key");

Comment: @JekinKalariya turn that into an answer. Plus: (1) servlets should not use fields, everything handled inside the method itself: doGet/doPost and such. (2) Naming convention in java does not use Hungarian notation (type prefixes like `str`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your field with in session then you need to set it as servlet session attribute like below.

with HttpServletRequest attribute inside doGet or doPost

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("key","value");
```

in your other servlet B you need to access it like this

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("key")
```

If you want it to any other scope like application or request you need to set it acordingly refer http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html